# Why am I always last pick in ranked?

Tags: league-of-legends

It's the 9th time in a row, so I believe it's not just bad luck. Pick order was supposed to be random for some time now.

I heard some possible reasons, as being chat restricted or any other punishment for negative attitude, yet I have none afaik.

Care to enlighten me?

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted your question when something like this happens, which seems very suspicious to me (as if the game were changed and that change weren't noticed somehow in the most recent patch notes after the one linked by Jutschge).

Comment: Well, probably someone who thinks I'm lying and possibly just trying to find a way to express my "rage". It happens a lot. It's just boring at worst in my case though :p

Comment: Note there is about a 1/2,000,000 chance of getting 9 last picks in a row. While that seems really, really low (and it is!) remember that as of January 2014, there are 27 million league players every day. So it happens to at least 3 people a day on average, and that's if they only average 1 game each!!

Comment: I'm guessing you're Silver or Bronze due to the fact that pick order still influences roles a large amount. -- BTW, this is not meant as an insult, this is just a guess. :D

Comment: I should point out that the pick order in ranked used to be based on your MMR - although it was patched out several versions ago with the switch to ladder based rankings.

Comment: @Mark I'm plat :p

Comment: I see. I just seem to never have this problem because my main is support, and everyone knows that support mains always get their role. Haha! D3 btw, but I guess my account has decayed since I left the Philippines.

Comment: Well yeah, it was indeed just awful bad luck. The streak ended at the 12th game.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**It is Random**](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-42-notes#02-13-hotfix)

You have been really unlucky if you were last pick 9 times in a row but that's just how the RNGods work. It's highly unlikely to be last pick 9 times in a row but it's not impossible.

Try to look at it from the bright side: Last pick means it's the easiest for you to counter.

Comment: eh, nope. You can't counter much when mid/top/adc are taken :D which is quite always the case in soloQ

Comment: Well it can be just that, unless you have proof that you're good in a specific role, by either looking by the match history or having a good win rate. But it's just increases your chances to convince people let you play the role you love/want, and that's it. [(if you feel to talk more about your experiences, you're welcome to the chat :P)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2348/summoners-rift)

Comment: When someone sends me a link with his win ratio for a champion, I actually don't care...